# removing \r from SQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem...

```
UPDATE `RtR`
SET
    rulings = REPLACE(rulings, '\r', '<br />');
```

When I run this, I get 0 rows modified.  But if I do a query for

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `RtR` 
    WHERE  `rulings` LIKE  '%\\r%';
```

I get 29 results... So I know those bastards are in there.  Any ideas?  This feels like a no-brainer, but I've been seeing zero results for hours now!

Answer (score 0):

May i know why you need an additional `\` in `'%\\r%'`?

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `RtR` 
    WHERE  `rulings` LIKE  '%\r%';
```

Comment: something about the way sql handles backslashes?  I don't know, really.  If I do a search in phpMyAdmin, for `rulings LIKE %...% \r` it add the other \ in the results.  Truth be told, searching with `'%\r%'` returns 0 results.

Comment: \ is an escape char in mysql,  \\ escapes the escape char so it's readable from a query. His text contain \r as text (not converted to return char) if I understood correctly, so the solution I guess (without trying) is to place \\r in the replace statement as well.